# Edit dictionary via QDialog not returning correct data

Tags: dictionary, pyqt

Trying to understand how to pass a dictionary to a QDialog function and get back the edited dictionary, I have searched but cannot find anything I can follow.
I am using a modal call so I need to close the dialog box before continuing.

The problem so far is that the application gets as far as the returnAttributes() function, at which point it prints out unexpected strings and does not close.

**dialog_grid.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class grid_dialog(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, **orig_attr):
        super(grid_dialog, self).__init__()
        self.initUI(**orig_attr)

    def initUI(self, **orig_attr):
        self.new_attr = orig_attr.copy()

        nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Name:")
        self.new_attr["name"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["name"])
        nameBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        nameBox.addStretch(1)
        nameBox.addWidget(nameLabel)
        nameBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["name"])

        shapeLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Shape:")
        self.new_attr["shape"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["shape"])
        shapeBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        shapeBox.addStretch(1)
        shapeBox.addWidget(shapeLabel)
        shapeBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["shape"])

        unitLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Unit:")
        self.new_attr["unit"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["unit"])
        unitBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        unitBox.addStretch(1)
        unitBox.addWidget(unitLabel)
        unitBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["unit"])

        scaleLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Scale:")
        self.new_attr["scale"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["scale"])
        scaleBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        scaleBox.addStretch(1)
        scaleBox.addWidget(scaleLabel)
        scaleBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["scale"])

        depthLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Depth:")
        self.new_attr["depth"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["depth"])
        depthBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        depthBox.addStretch(1)
        depthBox.addWidget(depthLabel)
        depthBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["depth"])

        planeLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Plane:")
        self.new_attr["plane"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["plane"])
        planeBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        planeBox.addStretch(1)
        planeBox.addWidget(planeLabel)
        planeBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["plane"])

        originLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Origin:")
        self.new_attr["origin"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["origin"])
        originBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        originBox.addStretch(1)
        originBox.addWidget(originLabel)
        originBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["origin"])

        acceptButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Accept')
        acceptButton.clicked.connect(self.returnAttributes)

        cancelButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Cancel')
        cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.discardAttributes)

        actionBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        actionBox.addStretch(1)
        actionBox.addWidget(acceptButton)
        actionBox.addWidget(cancelButton)

        attribBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        attribBox.addStretch(1)
        attribBox.addLayout(nameBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(shapeBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(unitBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(scaleBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(depthBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(planeBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(originBox)
        attribBox.addLayout(actionBox)

        self.setLayout(attribBox)    
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Attributes')
        self.show()

    # this is not working
    def returnAttributes(self):
        print self.new_attr
        return self.new_attr
        QtGui.QDialog.close(self)

    def discardAttributes(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.close(self)




def main():
    # Test case
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    part_attr = {}
    part_attr["name"] = "name1"
    part_attr["shape"] = "shape1"
    part_attr["unit"] = "unit1"
    part_attr["scale"] = "scale1"
    part_attr["depth"] = "depth1"
    part_attr["plane"] = "plane1"
    part_attr["origin"] = "origin1"
    part_attr["action"] = "action1"

    # Print original data    
    print part_attr

    # Edit data 
    part_attr = grid_dialog(**part_attr)

    # Print edited data
    print part_attr

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output from scipt:**

```
emos@bob:~/Python_scripts/dialog$ ./dialog_grid.py 
{'origin': 'origin1', 'scale': 'scale1', 'name': 'name1', 'shape': 'shape1', 'depth': 'depth1', 'plane': 'plane1', 'action': 'action1', 'unit': 'unit1'}
<__main__.grid_dialog object at 0xb70a64ac>
{'origin': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a6a4c>, 'scale': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a67c4>, 'name': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a653c>, 'depth': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a689c>, 'shape': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a6614>, 'plane': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a6974>, 'action': 'action1', 'unit': <PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0xb70a66ec>}
emos@bob:~/Python_scripts/dialog$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Classes should have CamelCase names: `GridDialog` instead of `grid_dialog`
2. You call the class `grid_dialog` but inherit it from `QtGui.QWidget`? Usually for showing a form with field for setting up some data `QDialog` is used.
3. This is wrong:

   ```
   def discardAttributes(self):
       QtGui.QDialog.close(self)
   ```

   First, because of point 2. Second, you can just use `self.close()`
4. You could make your code more readable, if using something like this:

   ```
   def __init__(self, **orig_attr):
       super(grid_dialog, self).__init__()
       self.initUI(**orig_attr)

   def initUI(self, name, shape, unit, ...):
       ...
   ```
5. To pass some data to to a dialog and get some result from it usually a [`QDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html) is used.

> A dialog window is a top-level window mostly used for short-term tasks
>   and brief communications with the user.

Also one particularity of `QDialog` is that it can be `accepted` or `rejected`. When a modal dialog is accepted/rejected you get the corresponding return code, **BUT** the window is not closed, but just hidden, so you can read all the values from the dialog.

So you need to inherit your class from `QDialog` and change

```
    acceptButton.clicked.connect(self.returnAttributes)
    cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.discardAttributes)
```

to

```
    acceptButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
    cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)
```

Also change:

```
    nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Name:")
    self.new_attr["name"] = QtGui.QLineEdit(orig_attr["name"])
    nameBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    nameBox.addStretch(1)
    nameBox.addWidget(nameLabel)
    nameBox.addWidget(self.new_attr["name"])
```

to

```
    nameLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Name:")
    self.nameEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(name)
    nameBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    nameBox.addStretch(1)
    nameBox.addWidget(nameLabel)
    nameBox.addWidget(self.nameEdit)
```

Then use something like:

```
dialog = GridDialog(...)
return_code = dialog.exec()
if return_code == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    # get the data
    dialog.nameEdit.text()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, I'm finding it difficult to pick up the Python language and this helps.  I will make the changes you suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I made the changes and it works. Is it possible to pass the edited objects in a dictionary back to the calling program?  I was thinking that would make the function more flexible in the future,  assuming I figure out how to create the labels and edit objects dynamically.

Comment: > I'm finding it difficult to pick up the Python language < This is not about Python, it's about Qt framework. > Is it possible to pass the edited objects in a dictionary back to the calling program < Make a wrapper function that will open the modal form passing it initial data, will analyze return code and will extract the data back and return a dictionary with the data. Again, it's not about Python, it's about so called programming patterns.